# How to constraint column of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, constraints

like:

```
create table test(
    score integer unsigned between 1 and 100
...
);
```

Is it possible to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: MySQL does not support CHECK constraints, although for compatibility with other engines it will parse them (but ignores them).

See: [MySQL and Check Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706231/mysql-and-check-constraints)

Comment: Mysql doesn't support CHECK Constraint

Comment: It will parse it and you will think it is legal, but it won't enfoce it

Answer (score 1):

Mysql doesn't support CHECK constraints

You can create BEFORE UPDATE/INSERT TRIGGER with RAISE ERROR

**EDIT:** Raise Error with

> SET new.score = 1 / 0;

Something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF  NEW.score < 1 OR NEW.score > 100
              SET NEW.score = 1 / 0; 
  END;
```