# Mysql table layout with multiple values for same column

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am integrating a friends system for my website...

One question I have about the mysql table is how it is to be set up.

Will I have many columns for each friend they add, such as freind 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on and the row will be the user who has added them.

Is there a better way to do this?? With my first thought doing it that way would mean a cap on  the amount of friends someone can have...

Comment: Doing that you would have a 1-row table wouldn't you ? That is not really clever DB design. I'm thinking about something like 1 table (id, friend.id, friend_id_who_added) and other table friend (id, name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion of multiple columns would violate [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). As well as artificially restricting the number of friends such structures are tedious to work with and inefficient.

You need a junction table for friends with 2 columns (`userid1`,`userid2`) that form a composite primary key. Both columns would have a FK relationship with the `user` table.

In many RDBMSs you would also have a check constraint `userid1 > userid2` so a relationship can only be stored in one form but I believe check constraints are [somewhat broken in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706231/mysql-and-check-constraints).

Comment: +1: Only caveat is the composite primary key won't stop reverse duplicates.  IE: 1,2 and 2,1 are considered valid composite PK values

Comment: Ok do you have any links to where I could learn this technique, thanks

Comment: @carlgoder - The gist of my answer is really about normalisation. Worth reading the wiki articles on [first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), [second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) and [third](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) normal forms.

Answer (score 2):

You will need an additional table with records for each friend a member has. For example:

```
members (id, name)
friends (member1, member2)
```